# linqpad error using Rx Reactive extensions in c#

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive, linqpad

What am I doing wrong ? I just downloaded the latest Rx sdk, installed. Using vs 2010, .net 4 have all latest sp/updates etc. Downloaded/installed linqpad, Added reference to the reactive dll as shown in the attached screenshot. Added the one line as shown in the linqpad demo but get an error when I run. Please advise. Right click on image and view image for clear view.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The download on the Rx home page is not actually the latest Rx SDK. The latest release is on the [Reactive Extensions Team Blog site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/) and is currently the <strike>Christmas 2010</strike> <strike>May 2011</strike> [June 2011 release](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26649).

In the release you're using, the Observable class is in the **System.Reactive.Linq** namespace (rather than the System.Linq namespace). Press F4 again and enter `System.Reactive.Linq` into "Additional Namespace Imports". (Or if you have autocompletion, a smart tag will appear and do the job for you).

This will get you up and running with Rx in LINQPad. Calling **.Dump()** on an observable is non-blocking, so you can Dump multiple observables at once.

For example:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(5).Dump("1 second");
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5)).Take(5).Dump(".5 second");
```

The result:

```
.5 second → 0
1 second → 0
.5 second → 1
.5 second → 2
1 second → 1
.5 second → 3
.5 second → 4
1 second → 2
1 second → 3
1 second → 4
```

The query will finish when all the observables have ended (or you press Cancel).

To run another reactive query, press **Ctrl+Shift+N**. This creates a new query with the same properties (references, namespace imports, etc). Another trick, if you have autocompletion, is to click 'Save as Snippet' after adding the assembly / namespace import. Then whenever you type the shortcut (e.g., 'rx') and press tab, the references and namespaces will be added automatically.

Comment: I cannot believe my question was answered by the venerable Mr Albahari. I have learned so much from  your threading, pfx tutorials. Basically a big fan like most of us in  this community. I will do as per your suggestion and also plan to buy a pro license of this tool for intellisense and other features. thank you

Comment: Actually, there are two releases *after* the Christmas release. The latest release is http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26225 - +1 on Joe's tool though, it's fantastic for exploring both Linq and Rx!

Comment: Thanks - I've just downloaded that release and noticed it supports the new GetAwaiter pattern, so you can await observables in the latest async CTP!

Comment: Where did you see the GetAwaiter pattern in the new Reactive DLLs? I did a quick search under Reflector of System.Reactive v 1.0.10605 and didn't spot anything with the string "Await" in it.

Comment: It's in the System.Reactive.Linq.Observable class: public static AsyncSubject<TSource> GetAwaiter<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source)

Answer (score 2):

Switch to the other tab in the dialog and add `System.Reactive` and `System.Reactive.Linq` in the namespace list